# I can't get my labels to display, however the rest of the textboxes and buttons display correctly, can anyone help me?

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, blazor

I have created a modal which allows me to register a contact, at the first moment in which I did it everything was displayed fine, but then the labels were no longer displayed and I can't find a way to solve it, here is my code:

```
<div class="modal fade @modalClass" id="staticBackdrop" style="display:@modalDisplay" data-bs-backdrop="static"  data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Crear Contacto</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick:preventDefault="true" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" @onclick=@Hide></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <EditForm Model="@contacto">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="h6 mb-2">Nombre</label>
                        <div class="input-text">
                            <InputText class="form-control" id="nombre" @bind-Value="contacto.Nombre" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="h6 mb-2" for="apellido">Apellido</label>
                        <div class="input-text">
                            <InputText class="form-control" id="apellido" @bind-Value="contacto.Apellido" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="h6 mb-2" for="mail">Email</label>
                        <div class="input-text">
                            <InputText class="form-control" id="mail" @bind-Value="contacto.Mail" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="h6 mb-2" for="documento">Documento</label>
                        <div class="input-text">
                            <InputText class="form-control" id="documento" @bind-Value="contacto.Documento" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="h6 mb-2" for="celular">Celular</label>
                        <div class="input-text">
                            <InputText class="form-control" id="celular" @bind-Value="contacto.Celular" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </EditForm>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" @onclick:preventDefault="true" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" @onclick=@Hide>Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"@onclick=@Guardar>Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use the built-in developer tools of the browser to see where the labels are. Maybe a CSS style is hiding them. Maybe they're pushed down as Lewis says.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the labels are not showing because of the "br" tags in between each form-group div which are causing them to be pushed down.

I think the "br" tags are creating extra spacing between the form group, you can try adding margins or padding instead.

I've taken your code and rewrote some of it to remove the "br" tags and I added mb-3 (margin-bottom) to each form-group div to create spacing between them. You can adjust the margin as needed to suit your needs:

```
<div class="modal fade @modalClass" id="staticBackdrop" style="display:@modalDisplay" data-bs-backdrop="static"  data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Crear Contacto</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick:preventDefault="true" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" @onclick=@Hide></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <EditForm Model="@contacto">
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label class="h6 mb-2">Nombre</label>
                        <div class="input-text">
                            <InputText class="form-control" id="nombre" @bind-Value="contacto.Nombre" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label class="h6 mb-2" for="apellido">Apellido</label>
                        <div class="input-text">
                            <InputText class="form-control" id="apellido" @bind-Value="contacto.Apellido" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label class="h6 mb-2" for="mail">Email</label>
                        <div class="input-text">
                            <InputText class="form-control" id="mail" @bind-Value="contacto.Mail" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label class="h6 mb-2" for="documento">Documento</label>
                        <div class="input-text">
                            <InputText class="form-control" id="documento" @bind-Value="contacto.Documento" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label class="h6 mb-2" for="celular">Celular</label>
                        <div class="input-text">
                            <InputText class="form-control" id="celular" @bind-Value="contacto.Celular" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </EditForm>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" @onclick:preventDefault="true" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" @onclick=@Hide>Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"@onclick=@Guardar>Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```